# Linear Differential Equation imaginary factoring inconsistancy

Tags: calculus

Recently I have been improving my skills in Linear differential equations and I came across a problem with a rather problematic solution.

The problem is as follows:
(Already converted from y prime form, I assure without error, I have checked five times)

$D^2+D+1=0$

The solution provided is:

$y = (C_{1}\cos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})x+C_{2}\sin(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})x)\cdot e^{-x/2}$

It is clear to me why sin and cos are present, but seems to me this solution implies

$\lambda = a + bi = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Assuming,

$y_1 = e^{ax}\cos(bx), y_2 = e^{ax}\sin(bx)$.

I attempted a solution using the result obtained from the answers provided (and I believe it is not a typo as there are similar problems with similar solutions in the text I am using). The issue that I have run against is that upon attempting the imaginary factorization I cannot obtain a similar solution.

$D^2+D+1=0$

$(D+[-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i])^2 = 0$

$D^2 - D + \sqrt{3} D i - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = 0$

As is written, the expansion that I perform results in an expression different from the original. I assume I am making an error somewhere but I can't seem to find it and I've spent quite some time trying to figure out why.

I am sure it is some simple error that I have made and I would be extremely grateful if someone would be willing to take the time to point it out.

Thank You,

David

Comment: Very nice first post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. The characteristic equation has two distinct solutions which are are complex conjugate:
$$x^2+x+1=\left(x-\left(-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right)\cdot \left(x-\left(-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right).$$

Comment: Thanks!!! I think that has steered me in the correct direction, I totally forgot about conjugates. 
Happy solving :).

Comment: @David  Well done! If you are new here take a few minutes for a tour: math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Will do. I really enjoy maths and think I'll be using this site more in the future. Thanks for the introduction!

Comment: @David Yes, I think it is an excellent place to learn for all levels.